# Xcode C++ executable file cannot find and open .txt files

Tags: c++, xcode

I bulid my C+++ project use Xcode 8.2.1 and generate an executable file in Bulid folder. But when I double click this file, it shows like this:

```
Last login: Mon Mar 13 16:27:59 on ttys001
RMBP:~ star$ /Users/mac/Documents/XCode/RCPSP/Build/Products/Release/RCPSP ; exit;
Cannot open file!
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

I tried to put the executable file in the project's working directory, but it still didn't work. Does anyone who knows how to fix it? I can't appreciate more. My code reads the .txt file like this

```
ft=fopen("j30optima.txt","r");
    if(ft==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Cannot open file!"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
```

I figured out the answer. When I put all these txt files in /Users/mac folder, then double click the executable file, it works. But why I must put these files in /Users/mac? Can I change the setting? I want to make the executable file work when I put these txt files and it together, just like how .exe files work under Windows OS.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Start posting a [MCVE] of your code in your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42759107/edit)!

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text but post the text. Copy/Paste works here.

Comment: Thank you all. I re-writed my question and I will read The Tour carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You executable is stored in a separate folder. Double clicking the icon will not open the folder.

The executable is stored in the debug folder. ***To open it right click the executable and click 'open in Finder'***. Note that if you create files in your program or want to access files in your program those will need to go in this debug folder along side the executable.

[image: Show in finder]

**Edit:**
Build your program as debug. Use the executable as shown above and put files in that directory too. When you want to release your program, make an .exe, you can use tools such as gpp to build all your files together.

Comment: I built my program to release version and I put all the files that my program needs to read in the Build/Products/Release folder, but it still cannot open these files.